# Найти m-й столбец матрицы (m задается вводом) С++

Tags: c++

Я здесь работаю с файлами,мне нужно ввести m,и вывести этот столбец матрицы.К примеру если ввожу 3 то оно выводит 3 столбец из моей матрицы.Здесь матрица к примеру я взял 10х10(Масив двумерный числа задаю в тектовом файле откуда читаю).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#define N 10
#define M 10
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num,m;
    int array[N][M];
    ifstream read;
    ofstream write;
    read.open("File.txt");
    if (!read)cout << "@Error can't find file!\n";
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; read || i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
                read >> array[i][j];
            }
        }
        cin>>m;
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                cout << array[i][j] << ' ';
            cout << '\n';
//здесь нужен столбец матрицы

        }
        write.open("file1.txt");
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                write << array[i][j] << ' ';
            }
            write << '\n';
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Наверное так и не понял, в каком виде вам нужен столбец. Если надо вывести все его элементы, то `for (i = 0; i < N; i++) cout << array[i][m] << '\n';`

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cin >> arr[i][m-1];
}

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cout << arr[i][m-1];
}
```

если  я правильно тебя понял то n и m - индексы
смотри: сначала ты перебираешь числа столбца №n;
потом то же самое с выводом;
Это то, что требуется?